# Use Membership class in C# .Net winforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to integrate the `Membership` provider class to handle he roles and authentication in a Desktop application. I have run `reg_sql` against the database to create the necessary procedures and tables. In my `app config` I have added the application services connection string to point to my necessary database

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;User ID=user;Password=password"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I am debugging the application and when I call the `Membership.CreateUser()`, I get a success status returned, but when I check the database there is no record in the `user` or `membership` tables. However when I try to re-register a user with the same details I receive a duplicate userName status. Therefore the record must exist somewhere?

How do I configure the Membership class to point to my defined database?

Thanks in advance

**Edit** this is my entire app config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;User ID=user;Password=password"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

        <add name="CODS.Properties.Settings.CODSConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CODS;User ID=user;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup>



</configuration>
```

Comment: Do yo have Membership settings in your configuration?

Comment: please show you ApplicationServices and connection strings in web.config

Comment: also, which table are you checking? user entries get created in aspnet_users table

Comment: I needed to add a <system.web></system.web> tag to the app config file to declare membership